# Converting categorical network traffic features to numerical - ISCX VPN2016 dataset

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, scikit-learn, neural-network

I am working on classifying encrypted network traffic, using ISCX VPN2016 dataset, I want to implement a deep neural network technique for classifying.
Dataset includes 14 pcap files indicating 14 classes of traffic, I have exported pcap files as csv, added one column as class and merge them to make one file. But the problem is the data type of features, I could not convert them to numerical features, I have tried using suggested usual methods in Numpy, Pandas and Sklearn such as: `OneHotEncoder`, `LabelEncoder`, `astype`, `get_dummies`, ...
But none of them worked.

My question is what should I do exactly to convert these features? And if converting is needed at all?
Here's my code:

```
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer


seed = 9
np.random.seed(seed)
netTraffic = np.loadtxt('netTraffic_100each.csv', delimiter=',', skiprows=1)

# OneHotEncoder
make_column_transformer(
    (OneHotEncoder(), ['Source'], ['Destination'], ['Protocol'], ['Info']))

# LabelEncoder
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
le.fit(['Class'])
list(le.classes_)
le.transform(['Class'])
print(netTraffic.Class.dtypes)

X = netTraffic[:, 0:6]
Y = netTraffic[:, 6]

(X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test) = train_test_split(X, Y, test_size=0.3, random_state=seed)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(7, input_dim=6, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(6, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(14, init='uniform', activation='relu'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, Y_train, validation_data=(X_test, Y_test), nb_epoch=20, batch_size=5)

scores = model.evaluate(X_test, Y_test)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1] * 100))
```

Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/PycharmProjects/webmining/testNN/neuralNetusingtfSite.py", line 12, in <module>
    netTraffic = np.loadtxt('netTraffic_100each.csv', delimiter=',', skiprows=1)
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\webmining\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1141, in loadtxt
    for x in read_data(_loadtxt_chunksize):
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\webmining\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1068, in read_data
    items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\webmining\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 1068, in <listcomp>
    items = [conv(val) for (conv, val) in zip(converters, vals)]
  File "C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\webmining\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 775, in floatconv
    return float(x)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Dell_b2:5b:a6'
```

First several rows of data:

[image]

I have also updated the csv file I am using for this code here: https://gofile.io/?c=L8UNYb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [pd.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('netTraffic_100each.csv')
df_encoded = pd.get_dummies(df, drop_first=True)
..
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks:) I read the documentation but I think I didnt get what drop_first does? If it's True it will keep the first column, right?

Comment: When dealing with categorical data, while hot encoding them you might run into [multicollinearity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicollinearity). You would want to avoid that, for example, let's say you have 3 categories A, B, and C in a column, upon hot encoding you have 3 columns: `col_A, col_B, col_c` with the combination of values `(1,0,0) or (0,1,0) or (0,0,1)`. Given you know, col_A is 1 and col_B is 0 then it is quite obvious col_C will be 0 which is what I mentioned `multicollinearity` is.